# Why CI library not sending email neither showing error

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am trying to send Email through Codeigniter Email library following is my setup
`

```
           $config['protocol']    = 'smtp';
           $config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
           $config['smtp_port']    = '465';
           $config['smtp_timeout'] = '60';
           $config['smtp_user']    = 'zahoorulhaq37@gmail.com';
           $config['smtp_pass']    = '****';
           $config['charset']    = 'utf-8';
           $config['newline']    = '\r\n';
           $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
       
           $config['validation'] = TRUE;
           // bool whether to validate email or not

           $this->email->initialize( $config );
           $this->email->from( 'zahoorulhaq37@gmail.com' );
           $this->email->to( 'zahoorulhaq37@hotmail.com' );
           $this->email->subject( 'testing' );
           $this->email->message( 'testingg' );
           $sent =  $this->email->send();
          if ( !$sent ) {
             echo $this->email->print_debugger();
                }
                 echo $sent;`
```

But it just timeouts and I get neither the response which should be true and neither gets an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the error in your email library you must set the send method to false like so:

```
$this->email->send(false);
```

Then the debugger will work. Otherwise the debugger has nothing to show.

```
echo echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Also if you're sending email with smtp with ssl you might need an additional config.

```
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'ssl';
```

Comment: adding this config throughs another error, which says Message:  fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

Comment: try changing this $config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'; to this $config['smtp_host']    = 'smtp.gmail.com';

Comment: Trying this gives error  Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

At least it shows some error now

Comment: Can it be some problem with my machine?? I am stupid I know

Comment: That means your local environment can't send those emails but it will probably work in your production environment.

Comment: Thanks for your time I was thinking the same

Comment: @ZahoorUlHaq can you mark my answer as correct since now what you have is a different problem and the connection to that smtp server can be established. You just dont have the environment to actually send the email.